# Eyes wrong position after import

Tags: unity

This is how my character looks in Blender:

[image]

After importing him to Unity, the eyes are no longer positioned correctly:
[image]

What could the problem be? How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is your character in the default pose? It looks like the eyes are incorrectly weighted to something that is not the head bone.

Comment: @JudeDesir I'm quite new to this so I'm not sure. In unity, he is in the T-pose and in blender, I have ALT+G and ALT+R'ed him so I would say he is in the default pose. How do I check if there is a problem with the weighting?

Comment: Not sure. You want to  check and see if the eyes are assigned to multiple vertex groups:
https://easyblend.org/html/modeling/meshes/vertex_groups/vertex_groups.html

Can you upload a blend file so that I can look at it when I get home?

Comment: @JudeDesir I have added my .blend file. Thank you so much dude!

Comment: Huh, I think this same thing happened to me when I was modding Quake Wars. Your eyes are children of the vertex group 'Eyes', but I can't find that bone. Where is it? Shouldn't your eyes be children of 'Eye.R' and 'Eye.L' respectively?

Comment: @JudeDesir Hmm I'm not sure. When I click on e.g. my left eye, "Eye.L", under "Object" it says that the parent is the bone "Eye.L". Regarding the vertex group, under "Data" when I press "Select" on "Eyes" after going into Edit mode of an eye, it correctly selects all the vertices of that eye?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your skinning.

For a mesh to be deformed by a bone, you need this mesh to be assigned to a vertex group named exactly like the bone.

Your eyes are assigned to a single vertex group named "Eyes", while you have two bones, named "Eye.L" and "Eye.R". So you have to remove that "Eyes" group, create new groups with the bones's names and assign the geometry accordingly.

Also, for each bone not supposed to deform the mesh, you should uncheck the Deform panel:

[image: demo pic]

This will avoid unnecessary calculations, memory overload, and such non-deforming bones won't create vertex groups as they don't need to.

Comment: After doing this, if you for example start my "Idle" animation, the eyes are not in their sockets anymore. Is there an easy way to fix this, or do I have to manually set the position of the eyes for all my animations to place them in the sockets?

Comment: Remove the armature deform modifiers on each eye, select both of them in object mode, then the armature in object mode, and do Ctrl P → Armature deform. It will just recreate the armature deform modifiers, and you should be good from there.

Comment: When I unchecked "Deform" on the eyes, it worked. After doing the last steps with Ctrl + P the eyes no longer moved with the rest of the mesh?

Comment: Because you set their bones to not deform. Don't set bones not to deform if you want them to deform.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete newb and you didn't tell me to recheck the "Deform" button after unchecking. Anyway, it works now. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I wrote `for each bone not supposed not to deform the mesh`, I meant `for each bone not supposed to deform the mesh`.

Comment: Yeah, but you also wrote here in the comments `Remove the armature deform modifiers on each eye`. But yea, the mistake is probably on me for misunderstanding something. We should probably stop discussing this though. Again, thank you very much for your help.